# Dateformatter to get Date From String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsdateformatter

My string is something like this,  `2012-12-08 17:00:00.0`. Now I am trying to retrieve date from this string by using NSDate formatter. My code is

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss"]; 
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"2012-12-08 17:00:00.0"];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",date1);
[df release];
```

But all I am getting is null value alone..

I have tried several types to dateFormatter like, `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss`, `YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS`.. but still no use.. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: dateFromString:@"" ? Of course you'll get null.

Comment: I am getting array of strings from database.. Now i have to get date from that string.. What ll be the best way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have just put an empty string literal in the post by mistake and your actual dates are as described in your post, you need to use `HH` instead of `hh` to parse hours in 24-hour system. You also need to add `.S` to your format string to parse the last zero of your time string:

```
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.S"];
//                 here -------^^       ^------ and here
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"2012-12-08 17:00:00.0"];
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
```

This produces the expected output (the difference in the hours is due to timezone difference):

```
2012-08-12 21:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: @user1402675 No problem! If an answer works for you, consider accepting it by clicking a checkmark outline next to it. This would indicate that you are no longer actively looking for an improved answer, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is a duration gap after seconds, and also you had missed strDate in dateformatter input.

```
NSString *strDate = @"2012-12-08 17:00:00.0";
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss.S"]; 
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:strDate];// formatter format
NSLog(@"%@ %@",date);
[df release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
NSString *strDate = @"2012-12-08 17:00:00.0";
NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.S"]; 
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:strDate];// forgot to add valid string for according to date formatter format
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
[df release];
```

Comment: You also forgot the two format specifiers. OP is using %@ %@ and printing just one object.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work.. Finally i found.. This is the right one.. NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.S"];
//                 here -------^^       ^------ and here
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"2012-12-08 17:00:00.0"];
NSLog(@"%@",date1);

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSString *currentDate=[dateformat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"PrintToday Date is %@ ",currentDate);
```

NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@""];

**you need to pass string in the your above line**